# How to print the value in dic in order?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I want to print the key whose 0-th index element in its value is 1.

For example, the `3`:

```
[[1, 3], [0, 3], [1, 3], [0, 3], [1, 3]]
```

The value are:

```
[[1, 3], [0, 3], [1, 3], [0, 3], [1, 3]]
```

Each 0-th index element in value is:

```
1 0 1 0 1
```

So the elements that meet the requirement are:

```
[1,3],[1,3],[1,3]
```

I want to print its key once. So the result should be 3.

Here is the code:

```
data_set = {'1': [[0, 0], [0, 0]], '2': [[0, 2]], '3': [[1, 3], [0, 3], [1, 3], [0, 3], [1, 3]], '4': [[1, 4]], '5': [[1,5], [1,5], [1,5]]}
z = ""
for k,v in data_set.items():
    for item in v:
        if item[0] == 1:
            count = 0
            if z == "" or z[count] != k:
                z += k
            count +=1
print z
```

The result I got is:

```
35554
```

The expected result should be:

```
345
```

I don't know why it firstly prints the `key=3`'s value, then moves to `key=5`'s part.

I guess that's the part that makes my "if statement" doesn' work. Because in that part, I check whether the key has been printed.

What's wrong with it and how to print the value in dic in order?

Comment: Dictionary is intrinsically unordered. What is printed first is pretty much random. So your result can be "345" as well as "534". Or do you want specifically "345"? Another questions: do you indeed want the output as a string?

Comment: I recommend using something along the lines of calling sorted(set(z)) on z to sort it and do duplicate elimination. But first you should keep the values in an array and if string is a requirement for you do that last.

Answer (score 0):

You could use following code to print the keys in order:

```
print ''.join(k for k, v in sorted(data_set.iteritems()) if any(x[0] == 1 for x in v)) # 345
```

Since dictionaries are unordered `data_set.items()` will return the key value pairs in random order. That explains why 5 is before 4 in your output. This problem can be easily fixed by sorting the returned items before iterating over them: `sorted(data_set.items())`.

The second problem is that since you always check if the string is empty or first character matches to the current key. This explains why there are multiple 5's on your result. That can be fixed by changing `if` clause to check last character instead:

```
if z == "" or z[-1] != k:
    z += k
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print key `k` even if there is only single value starting with `1` in value `v` then you don't need to count anything. Just do

```
z = ''
for k, v in data_set.items():
    for item in v:
        if item[0] == 1:
            z += k
            break
```

On a side note, use `iteritems` instead of `items` if you are not on Python3 (which you are not, as you tagged the question python2.7). `iteritems` is efficient than `items`.